# Javascript Associative Array Becomes Empty On AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, post

I am in a problem. I have a page with several `text` field with same class name and different `attribute values`. I would like to create an array which having `unique` key with joining the `text field` `attribute` values. And pass it to a `PHP` page using `ajax`.

My problem is

**I can create the array successfully. But when I try to send the data through ajax, it become empty and the post array did not contain that value. But when I try to `console` the array, then it has the value**

**My JQuery code is**

```
$(document).on('click', '#mybutton', function () {

    var c_array = [];
    $('.class').each(function(){

        var val1 = $(this).attr('attr1');
        var val2 = $(this).attr('attr2');
        var val3 = $(this).attr('attr3');
        var key = val1+'_'+val2+'_'+val3;
        var no = $(this).val();
        c_array[key] = no;
        alert(c_array[key]);
    });
    console.log(c_array);
    var type = 'check_cookie';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'action.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: { type: type, c_array: c_array },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.msg !== '' && data.msg !== null) {
                window.location = 'new.php';
            }
            else {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What is the problem with this code? Please help me. Thank u all in advance....

Comment: provide your php code and html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared your `c_array` as an array, [you should assign it numeric indices](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) (or `key`s as per your codes). If you need to work with an associative array (i.e. non-numeric indices), you can either instantiate `c_array` as a javascript object, a json data structure or an array of javascript objects.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/tu5oLkr6/) or the stack snippet below.

```js
// an array with numeric indices works.
// some_array has 2 entries.
var my_array = new Array()
my_array[0] = 'Test 1'
my_array[1] = 'Test 1'
var my_type = 'My Type 1'
var my_data = {type: my_type, some_array: my_array}
console.log(my_data)

// an array with non-numeric indices doesn't work.
// some_array is an empty array.
var my_array2 = new Array()
my_array2['a'] = 'Test 2'
my_array2['b'] = 'Test 2'
var my_type2 = 'My Type 2'
var my_data2 = {type: my_type2, some_array: my_array2}
console.log(my_data2)

// an array of objects work.
// some_array has 2 entries.
var my_array3 = new Array()
my_array3[0] = {'a': 'Test 3'}
my_array3[1] = {'b': 'Test 3'}
var my_type3 = 'My Type 3'
var my_data3 = {type: my_type3, some_array: my_array3}
console.log(my_data3)

// an object works.
// some_array has 2 entries.
var my_var_obj = {a: 'Test 4', b: 'Test 4'}
var my_type4 = 'My Type 4'
var my_data4 = {type: my_type4, some_array: my_var_obj}
console.log(my_data4)

// a JSON data structure works.
// some_array has 2 entries.
var my_var_obj = $.toJSON({'a': 'Test 5', 'b': 'Test 5'})
var my_type5 = 'My Type 5'
var my_data5 = {type: my_type5, some_array: my_var_obj}
console.log(my_data5)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. I changes the index as numeric and it works just fine... :)